# Does backend proxy double the traffic? Is there a way for frontend to implement a proxy connection?

Tags: nginx, proxy

If I have A (Client) => B (Ngix Server) => C (Proxy) => D (Content) structure, will server B double the traffic of using proxy C ?

Is there a way for the front end to connect to proxy C directly with javascript and then connect to content server D?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are usually requests for static data in a frontend. So nginx can be configured in front of backend (server) and frontend (content), proxying the requests to one or the other instance (or resources) depending on route. An exception can be when your backend logic is allowing access to some content (yet it might be solved by more complex configuration).

Comment: Will the Nginx server double the traffic?

Comment: If content instance is on another server and you want to keep nginx as proxy - it will request content from there. If that is located in external network - then it will be external traffic.